# 2D Array Behaving Weird

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

```
        int[][] array = new int[3][3];
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++){
            array[j][i] = j;
            System.out.print(array[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println();

    }
```

Hi, I am bit confused as to why the output of the code above is:

```
000
110
222
```

I was expecting:

```
000
111
222
```

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the arrays as `array[j][i]` and printing as `array[i][j]`.

So you're assigning `array[2][1]` as `2`
But you're printing `array[1][2]` which is at that time `0`.

Although by the end of the program your array would be similar to what you're expecting.
By default, integer arrays are assigned with 0s.

Comment: Okay I see that, so its printing array[1][2] as 0, as it has not yet been assigned and therefore has default value of 0 and that is whats being printed. Thanks for your help.